# \. は何を意味していますか？

Tags: swift

`SwiftyUserDefaults`というオープンソースがあります。

https://github.com/sunshinejr/SwiftyUserDefaults/blob/566ace16ee91242b61e2e9da6cdbe7dfdadd926c/README.md

バージョン4のときは、

上記READMEにあるとおり

引用：

```
extension DefaultsKeys {
    static let username = DefaultsKey<String?>("username")
    static let launchCount = DefaultsKey<Int>("launchCount", defaultValue: 0)
}

let username = Defaults[.username]
Defaults[.hotkeyEnabled] = true
```

という使い方だったのですが、

バージョン5では

https://github.com/sunshinejr/SwiftyUserDefaults

にある通り

引用：

```
extension DefaultsKeys {
    var username: DefaultsKey<String?> { return .init("username") }
    var launchCount: DefaultsKey<Int> { return .init("launchCount", defaultValue: 0) }
}

// Get and set user defaults easily
let username = Defaults[\.username]
Defaults[\.hotkeyEnabled] = true
```

と　`\.` を使うようになっていました。　`\.`　は何を意味するのでしょうか？

Comment: 詳しくないのですがkey-path-expressionでしょうか…… [Swift: What does backslash dot “\.” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52543502/5989200)　／　追記: 下にある[Tatsuhiro SAWAさんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/59115/19110)がほぼ同じことを解説くださってます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\.username` は Swift 4 で導入された KeyPath だと思います。

Objective-Cやそれ以前のSwiftでもキーパスという概念はあり、使用することができましたが、
それはキーパスを文字列として渡すので型安全性がないものでした。
Swift 4 の KeyPath を使えば型安全性をコンパイラが保証することができるようになりました。

ちょっとした例

```
struct User {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

var user = User(id: "1", name: "hoge", age: 20)

let kp: AnyKeyPath = \User.id // 型を限定しないKeyPath型
print(user[keyPath: kp]) // Optional("1")

let kp2:PartialKeyPath<User> = \.name  // KeyPathの型が限定されていれば、型名を省略して \.〜 と記載できる
print(user[keyPath: kp2]) // hoge
```

SwiftyUserDefaults というライブラリについてはよく知りません。
使用例の見た目だけだと、余計な `\` が増えているだけに見えますが、
おそらくKeyPathを使うことでより型安全性が高まるなど、何らかのメリットがあって対応したのでしょう。

Answer (score -1):

`\.`は特別な意味をもつかもしれない`.`を`\`で抑止しているように見えます。

Comment: 訳に立つ回答ではありませんでした。どなたか知りませんがマイナス投票で信用度を使わせてしまい、すみませんでした。自戒の意味で回答は削除しないつもりです。